# Which document is used for post deployment and what is its name/content?

Tags: manual-testing, terminology, development-process, test-strategy, test-report

Which document is used for post deployment or what is the name of that document.

And what things does this document include?

Comment: What do you mean by "used for post deployment"? Didn't you mean "used for ("verifying XYZ", "communicate XYZ") post deployment"?

Comment: Your question is not that clear. I think it might be release notes.

Answer (score 2):

An example comes to mind:

1. "Change request" - user wants additional changes that are not in the original scope of the app, this also includes any additional requests from the user

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the goal of the document. This could differ per industry/company. Maybe a better question would be: "Examples of post-deployment documentation".

Personally I see no need for any post-deployment documentation. Most documentation can be produced before deployment, for example, the changelog which informs users what changes where deployed.

> Working software **over** comprehensive documentation
>
> That is, while there is value in the items on
>   the right, we value the items on the left more.
>
> https://agilemanifesto.org/

Challenge yourself and your teams if you really need more documentation. Who benefits from the post-deployment documentation? How often would they really use it? Could an email to key stakeholders be enough? Something like: "Deployment was complete, smoke tests successful, the system is operational with the new version. See the changelog here.".

Answer (score 0):

A mandatory process that any software testing company should follow is to provide Sanity Report and Release Notes to the client and stakeholders post-deployment on the live environment.

Sanity report should have information regarding if the list of changes is successfully deployed or not.
It should also document any changes that were planned but were missed.

Release notes should include the below details.

- All the requirements that were catered for the referred sprint
- All the requirements which were deferred from the referred sprint to the future ones
- A brief description of the tasks catered with the URLs of the updates(if available)
- Any specific process to perform to check the updates on the live environment(say clearing of cache or a hard refresh)